# How to convert a public key string to a eosio::publickey object inside a smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract

The smart contract takes a string as an input for the public key. I need to convert it into a public key object within the contract.

Answer (score 1):

You would do it as follows:

```
eosio::public_key string_to_public_key(unsigned int const key_type, std::string const & public_key_str)
{
  eosio::public_key public_key;
  public_key.type = key_type; // Could be K1 or R1 enum
  for(int i = 0; i < 33; ++i)
  {
    public_key.data.at(i) = public_key_str.at(i);
  }
  return public_key;
}
```